# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported for ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, angular

I am recieving the following error:
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (D:\Licenta-2023\Home X Change\Home X Change Front\Home X Change Front\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:145:18)
at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (D:\Licenta-2023\Home X Change\Home X Change Front\Home X Change Front\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:46:50)
at OriginalSource.updateHash (D:\Licenta-2023\Home X Change\Home X Change Front\Home X Change Front\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\OriginalSource.js:104:8)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\Licenta-2023\Home X Change\Home X Change Front\Home X Change Front\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:868:17)
at handleParseResult (D:\Licenta-2023\Home X Change\Home X Change Front\Home X Change Front\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:934:10)
at D:\Licenta-2023\Home X Change\Home X Change Front\Home X Change Front\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:1026:4
at processResult (D:\Licenta-2023\Home X Change\Home X Change Front\Home X Change Front\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:743:11)
at D:\Licenta-2023\Home X Change\Home X Change Front\Home X Change Front\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:807:5

My package.json:
{
"name": "homexchange",
"version": "0.1.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"start:de": "ng serve --configuration=de --port=4201",
"build": "ng build",
"build:de": "ng build --configuration=de",
"watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
"test": "ng test",
"i18n:extract": "ng xi18n --output-path src/locale"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~12.1.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^12.1.4",
"@angular/common": "~12.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~12.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~12.1.0",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.34",
"@angular/forms": "~12.1.0",
"@angular/material": "^12.1.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~12.1.0",
"@ngbmodule/material-carousel": "0.7.1",
"@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^18.0.1",
"@types/file-saver": "^2.0.3",
"file-saver": "^2.0.5",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tslib": "^2.2.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
"@angular/cli": "~12.1.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.0",
"@angular/localize": "^12.1.4",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
"karma": "~6.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
"prettier": "^2.3.2",
"typescript": "~4.3.2"
}
}

I have tried some solutions here on stack overflow, but did not help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.